# Inserting the degree symbol into the word document using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-word, docx

I am using the python https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx module and I am trying to just simply add the degree symbol to my word document and can not see how to do it.

Just have a string something like this:

Degree = "some_numberº"

and then I want to insert that string in my document.

Comment: Has my answer worked for you ?

Comment: No, to be honest I am not sure what you mean by zip archive, opened the word/document.xml file and I could not do it.

Comment: I have updated my post to be more clear. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I have created an empty document with the following text inside it:

[image: EmptyDocx12Degrees]

- **saved** it as document.docx
- **renamed** document.docx to document.zip
- **opened** the zip and extracted it
- **opened** the file in folder **word** named **document.xml** file

This is a link documenting the structure of a word document 'of information purposes) : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/docx/info

Here's the content of the document.xml for the specific file with degrees inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
    <w:body>
        <w:p w:rsidR="009565D8" w:rsidRDefault="00986522">
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:cs="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial"/>
                    <w:color w:val="000000"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="21"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="21"/>
                    <w:shd w:color="auto" w:fill="FFFFFF" w:val="clear"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>12</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:r>
                <w:rPr>
                    <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:cs="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial"/>
                    <w:color w:val="000000"/>
                    <w:sz w:val="21"/>
                    <w:szCs w:val="21"/>
                    <w:shd w:color="auto" w:fill="FFFFFF" w:val="clear"/>
                </w:rPr>
                <w:t>º</w:t>
            </w:r>
            <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
            <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
        </w:p>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="009565D8">
            <w:pgSz w:h="16838" w:w="11906"/>
            <w:pgMar w:bottom="1417" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0" w:header="708" w:left="1417" w:right="1417" w:top="1417"/>
            <w:cols w:space="708"/>
            <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
        </w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

As you can see, they are tags: `<w:t></w:t>` . These tags contain the text of your document. One of them contains **12**, and the other contains the degree symbol.

So it is just stored as `º`, or charCode 186. To include your string, replace the charactercode of the degree in the string by the characterCode 186, it should work (with a regex for example)